# How to set Axis step in Google Chart?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm wondering how to set axis step in a google chart built from JavaScript?
I use this to set min and max:

```
vAxis: {
title: 'temps (ms)',
    viewWindowMode: 'explicit',
    viewWindow: {
        max: 180,
        min: 0
    },
}
```

And I need to add an other constraint to fix vertical step to 0.1 for example.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Finally I found a trick using :

```
     vAxis: {
        title: 'temps (ms)',
        viewWindowMode: 'explicit',
        viewWindow: {
          //max: 180,
          min: 0,
        },
        gridlines: {
          count: 10,
        }
      }
```

It don't set steps but instead, tell that

> max / (nb steps) = count (here it's **10**)

So for example with max set to **180**, each steps will have a value of **18** using `count: 10`.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with ticks:

```
vAxis: {
    title: 'temps (ms)',
    viewWindow: {
        min: 0,
        max: 180
    },
    ticks: [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180] // display labels every 10
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I essentially did what alain did, calculating the max value, multiplying it by 1.1 (to account for the padding above the max element on the chart) and dividing it by the steps I wanted to give me the steps I needed.

```
vAxis: {
  title: 'vAxis',
  minValue: 0,
  gridlines: {
    count: Math.ceil(max * 1.1 / interval) // try to pick the correct number to create intervals of 50000 
  }
}
```

where `max` is the max value and `interval` is the desired interval.
This has not been thoroughly tested, so the constant of `1.1` and using `Math.ceil` may need to be tweaked.