# Google chart api Line chart: Units don't match points

Tags: google-visualization, linechart

[image: Line chart where units don't match points]

I have a Google chart api Line chart where the horizontal axis units don't match the corresponding points on the chart. See the image.

I have used those options that makes sure that the h axis don't use decimal numbers:

```
hAxis: { title: 'some title', format: '#' }
```

I have used no other relevant options, and haven't found any options in the documentation that seems to could solve the issue..

**Update:** 
Code to generate the chart:

```
var options = { title: '<%# Strings.GameStatisticsView_GameProgressChart %>', hAxis: { title: '<%# Strings.ScoreBoard_RoundNr %>', format: '#' }, vAxis: { title: '<%# Strings.Common_Points %>' }, backgroundColor: { fill: 'transparent' }, elementId: 'GameProgressChart', column1: 'Round Nr' };
drawLineChart(response.d.Data, options);

...

drawLineChart: function (data, options) {
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn('number', options.column1);
    for (var j = 0; j < data.key.length; j++) {
        dataTable.addColumn('number', data.key[j]);
    }
    dataTable.addRows(data.value.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.value.length; i++) {
        dataTable.setValue(i, 0, data.value[i].key);
        for (var k = 0; k < data.key.length; k++) {
            dataTable.setValue(i, k+1, data.value[i].value[k]);
        }
    }

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById(options.elementId));        
    chart.draw(dataTable, options);   
},
```

**Solution from comments**:
The steps in your x axis can't be hardcoded but you can hardcode how many gridlines to have, see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104925/how-to-set-axis-step-in-google-chart).

Comment: Is there really not any one that knows anything about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you are still in need of an answer for this, but should anyone be in the same situation..

`format: '#'` forces the value format to 1 digit, so your 3 in the example is most likely around 3.3 but you only see the integer part because of the formatting applied.

Comment: I actually still have this problem - but havn't worked on it since.. But my dataset contains only 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 so it don't make sense.. But now I just tried to remove format: '#' and the values on the axis makes more sence.. But I need a line for every datapoint or just some of them - not somewhere in between.. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I can try. Could you please paste the code you are using to generate the chart?

Comment: Now I have added the code to generate the chart, but the data is from a webservice so it is not so easy to show.. Let me know if it don't make sense..

Comment: Hi Morten, how do the values make more sense now? If you only have 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 in your x axis it should not make a difference whether you format with '#' or don't format at all I think. The steps in your x axis can't be hardcoded but you can hardcode how many gridlines to have, see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104925/how-to-set-axis-step-in-google-chart). As for the data, difficult to take a guess without the actual data but I see you are assigning values to the x axis with `dataTable.setValue(i, 0, data.value[i].key)`, is key a value?

Comment: Have you tried to plot the dataTable instead of the chart and see if the values there make sense?

Comment: Nice - I guess if I hardcode the number of guidelines it would solve the problem(I will get back when I get the time to code it). The data is just mapped to KeyValuePair, so the key is x-axis and value is y-axis. The values make sense - I have them show in another type of table..

Comment: great. glad you got it sorted!